# Error occurred while store image path to SQLite Database using Android?

Tags: android, android-sqlite, android-sql

It continues to occur error... what is the problem?
every variables are String.

```
String insertSQL = "INSERT INTO " + DBHelper.getTableName() + " VALUES (\''"+entry.getKey()+"\'', \''"+images+"\'')";
```

---

Error message

> INSERT INTO LABELING RESULT VALUES (''Sky'',
>   ''["/storage/emulated/0/DCIM/CandyCam/IMG_20171009_164101723.jpg","/storage/emulated/0/DCIM/Pictail/IMG_20180305_000218777.jpg","/storage/emulated/0/DCIM/Pictail/IMG_20180401_235850170.jpg","/storage/emulated/0/DCIM/Pictail/IMG_20180518_194252232.jpg"]''))

My table has three column : ID(Integer), LABEL(TEXT), IMAGES(TEXT)

Comment: share your create table SQL query

Comment: My table has three column : ID(Integer), LABEL(TEXT), IMAGES(TEXT)

Comment: bareham, not that it's needed now (I've edited the question accordingly) but if you are asked for further information and have that information it's much better to edit the question and include it in the question. By all means reply to the comment as well.

Comment: @MikeT Thx for ur upvote

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue 1 you have specified a table name with a space i.e. LABELING RESULT, if this is the table name then you would need to enclose it e.g. [LABELING RESULT].

Issue 2 you have double single quotes when you should only have 1.

Issue 3 you have an extra closing parenthesis.

I believe the following is what you want :-

```
INSERT INTO [LABELING RESULT] VALUES ('Sky', '["/storage/emulated/0/DCIM/CandyCam/IMG_20171009_164101723.jpg","/storage/emulated/0/DCIM/Pictail/IMG_20180305_000218777.jpg","/storage/emulated/0/DCIM/Pictail/IMG_20180401_235850170.jpg","/storage/emulated/0/DCIM/Pictail/IMG_20180518_194252232.jpg"]'))
```

Which would (not checked though) be :-

```
String insertSQL = "INSERT INTO [" + DBHelper.getTableName() + "] VALUES ('"+entry.getKey()+"', '"+images+"')";
```

That assumes that **Sky** goes into the **LABEL** column and the 2 comma separated image paths go into the **IMAGES** column.

#### Additional re enclosing (the [ ] ):-

> If you want to use a keyword as a name, you need to quote it. There
>   are four ways of quoting keywords in SQLite:
>
> - 'keyword'       A keyword in single quotes is a string literal.
> - "keyword"       A keyword in double-quotes is an identifier.
> - [keyword]       A keyword enclosed in square brackets is an identifier. This is not
>     standard SQL. This quoting mechanism is used by MS Access and SQL
>     Server and is included in SQLite for compatibility.
> - `keyword`       A keyword enclosed in grave accents (ASCII code 96) is an identifier.
>     This is not standard SQL. This quoting mechanism is used by MySQL and
>     is included in SQLite for compatibility.

[SQL As Understood By SQLite - SQLite Keywords](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_keywords.html)

Comment: Does table name have to has bracket([])?

Comment: Yes, or other valid enclosing characters (will update answer accordingly) if it has a space, although personally I would not use a space perhaps an underscore. e.g. LABELING_RESULT.